# Making a Process call to be placed "Always on Top" or if not always comes on top when it's called?

Tags: java

I have a little call to odbcad32.exe from within my application.  The JFrame calling it is set to be "Always on Top".  However I would like the ODBC Manager window to open on top of everything else and not behind the JFrame calling it.  How can I have this process to Override the calling JFrame and show on top of it???!

```
Process p;
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C://WINDOWS/system32/odbcad32.exe");
```